# Grails - Copying hasMany relationships from one domain object to another?

Tags: grails, dns, grails-orm

During an archive process I am copying the details from an existing domain object to a new instance of that domain. Both domain objects have a hasMany relationship:

```
static hasMany = [pets:Pet]
```

When I have the following scenario:

```
def ownerOne = (logic to find owner)
def ownerTwo = new Owner
****ownerTwo.pets = ownerOne.pets****
```

How do I do that starred line? I've tired this:

```
Set<Pet> ownerTwoPets = new TreeSet<Pet>()
   for(Pet p : ownerOne.pets) {
      ownerTwoPets.add(p)
   }
ownerTwo.pets = ownerTwoPets
```

With no luck. I can do it with String objects in a hasMany without problem. But I cannot figure it out with domain objects in a hasMany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails has a built in method to add to a relationship like this one.  Try this:

```
ownerOne.pets.each { Pet p ->
  ownerTwo.addToPets(p)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - Much better way to handle this.